# cakePHP memcache logic not working

Tags: php, cakephp, windows-7, memcached, telnet

My problem is that memcache logic inside my cakePHP application is not working on my local system, ever since I set it up here, by taking code from existing setup of teammates. I have checked that Memcached service is running on my system and phpinfo() shows memcache section enabled.

But, things like these are not working -

```
$this->Memcache->set($key,$value);
```

CakePHP uses its wrapper for Memcache, v. 0.3.

If I debug like this -

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "checking";
error_reporting(-1); 
$this->Memcache->set($key,$countryNetworkWiseReportData,3600);
echo "finished";
exit;
```

I get -

> checkingfinished
> Strict standards: Non-static method Cache::write() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in D:\cake1.2\cake\libs\configure.php on line 690
>
> ... and similar strict standard notifications for Cache::getInstance() etc.

But note the notifications appear after "checkingfinished", so I am confused if that is actually relevant.

I tried the command -

```
telnet 127.0.0.1:11211
```

Which gives -

```
Connecting To 127.0.0.1:11211...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
```

Also tried -

```
telnet localhost:11211 (in case firewall issues prevent connection to 127.0.0.1)
```

But got the same error.

I also tried this script called memcache.php. I put `$arr= "127.0.0.1:11211";` in the code and I got this result on my system -

[image]

What do I interpret from this data? I am getting a Warning in the Start time section - `Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the ...`.

So far, it appears to me that connection to the default port 11211 is due to some reason not allowed in my cakePHP project code. But again, how then memcache.php is able to connect to the memcache server and able to display those data.

**Further Details**

Thanks to Tudor Constantin, doing `telnet 127.0.0.1 11211` does not throw any error anymore, shows an empty screen... which I guess is fine.

I checked further in code, we have model functions which have logic like this -

```
if(!$this->memcacheCommon())
{
    $this->log('Error in memcache', LOG_DEBUG);
    die('Error in memcache');
}

//like in others system, in my system too, it passes above condition

$memcachedata = $this->Memcache->get($key);
//does not return data in my system, because $this->Memcache->set($key,$data); never sets the data correctly.

if(got data from memcache)
{
    //Return that data
}
else
{
    //Get data from database
    $this->Memcache->set($key,$data); //does not the data in my setup - set() function returns false
}
```

So, I went inside the set() function of class CakeMemcache(), and there is this line in the end

```
return @$this->_Memcache_cluster_new->set($key, $var, 0, time()+$expires);
```

this returns false, and I don’t know what to debug from here.

One more thing that is confusing me is memcacheCommon() inside app_model.php has these lines –

```
$this->Memcache = new CakeMemcache();
$this->Memcache->_connect();
```

And inside CakeMemcache()->_connect(), there are these lines –

```
$this->_Memcache_standalone =& new Memcache();
$this->_Memcache_cluster_new =& new Memcache();
```

I am not sure what exactly do they do.

Will appreciate any pointers... thanks

**More Details**

I have somehow lost the earlier memcache.php file, using which I got the above graphical memcache usage display (had posted the pic of the output I got, above). I later downloaded memcache-3.0.6 from http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.6 and tried running the example.php and memcache.php files which are present inside the archive.

**Firstly**, running example.php gives me following error -

```
Notice: memcache_connect(): Server localhost (tcp 11211) failed with: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Warning: memcache_connect(): Can't connect to localhost:11211, A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Connection to memcached failed
```

I checked that memcached service is running (in windows services list).
Also `telnet localhost 11211` does not give any error and shows an empty command window.

**Secondly**, running memcache.php and entering the credentials, gives me the following, on clicking all the tabs (Refresh Data, View Host stats, variables ) -

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant values - assumed 'values' in path\to\file\memcache.php on line 57
Cant connect to:v:a
```

Line 57 was -

```
function get_host_port_from_server($server){
    $values = explode(':', $server);
    if (($values[0] == 'unix') && (!is_numeric( $values[1]))) {
        return array($server, 0);
    }
    else {
        return values;   //line 57
    }
}
```

How come that was values, I downloaded it from http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.6. After I changed it to `return $values;` I got ->

```
Cant connect to:mymemcache-server1:11211
```

. I don't exactly remember how earlier I was able to get that memcache server graph (I posted the pic above).

**Thirdly**, on command line, after connecting via telnet, command `stats` gives the following -

```
STAT pid 1584
STAT uptime 2856
STAT time 1315981346
STAT version 1.2.1
STAT pointer_size 32
STAT curr_items 0
STAT total_items 0
STAT bytes 0
STAT curr_connections 1
STAT total_connections 3
STAT connection_structures 2
STAT cmd_get 0
STAT cmd_set 0
STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 0
STAT bytes_read 7
STAT bytes_written 0
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
END
```

Comment: Where can I get the memcache.php script you are showing?

Comment: @Neo, you can get it from http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.6 -> Download latest link. Extract the archive, take the `memcache.php` file inside that to your web directory and browse memcache.php. PECL should be there installed.

Comment: Where in the cake configuration are the settings for the memcache server(s)?  Memcache can have a cluster of servers, and typically a class wrapper will go through the list of memcache servers and attempt to connect to them.

Comment: @gview -  Posted some **More details**.

Comment: @Neo - Posted some More details.

Comment: My problem is not solved yet... however awarded bounty because no other answers were there. I will keep checking this, answers are welcome. Thanks

Comment: @Sandeepan:  what happens when you try to "ping localhost"?  Does this work correctly?  It appears memcache is working correctly and you are able to access it from telnet on its port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! I found the solution!! It started working after I changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in the `/app/config/fcore.php` file.

Made the following changes -

```
# Memcache server constants
define('MEMCACHE_SERVER', 'localhost:11211');
define('MEMCACHE_SERVER_CLUSTER', 'localhost:11211');
define('MEMCACHE_SERVER_CLUSTER_NEW', 'localhost:11211');
```

to

```
# Memcache server constants
define('MEMCACHE_SERVER', '127.0.0.1:11211');
define('MEMCACHE_SERVER_CLUSTER', '127.0.0.1:11211');
define('MEMCACHE_SERVER_CLUSTER_NEW', '127.0.0.1:11211');
```

Oh, I suffered so much due to this and I think I could not, in my life, fix this.

Luckily, our team setup a new repository for the project with `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and when I took checkout memcache started working and later I realized this was the reason.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, you are on a windows machine, so the telnet command is:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Notice the *space* instead of *colon*. This might help you debug the memcache connection

Comment: please check my further details section in question

Comment: I have the smillar problem with you Sandeepan. I don't see anything on telnet